# Regarding adding a spacer div to fix a CSS floating div issue

Tags: css, css-float

I'm currently learning CSS. I'm struggling to to my form elements to be arranged correctly. especially the last element the `submitBtn` div, here's my issue :

[image]

The floated `submitBtn` div is not included inside the `formContainer` div, this is my code (with the `spacer` div is turned off) :

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding : 0;    
}

li {
    list-style : none;
}

#mainContainer {
    width : 760px;
    margin : 20px auto ;
    background-color : red;
}

#header {
    background-color: blue;
}

#formContainer {
    background-color : green;
}

#textInfo {
    background-color : yellow ;
}

#occupationInfo {
    background-color : purple ;
}

#hobbyInfo {
    background-color : pink ;   
}

#birthdayInfo {
    background-color : brown ;
}

#briefInfo {
    background-color : darkblue;
}

#submitBtn {
    width : 50px;
    float : right;
    clear : both;
    background-color : black ; 
}

/*#spacer {
    clear : both;
}*/
```

But when i uncomment it it fixes the problem :

[image]

Is there any cleaner solution other than adding a spacer div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with Diego's solution you can also try adding `overflow:auto` to formContainer. The reason this happens is because parent elements are never to expand to contain floated elements. A floated element will "overflow" its container.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) method.

Add the following code to your CSS:

```
/*** Clearfix ***/
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

Then assign class `clearfix` to your container `div`.